# Can't stop process; it's not currently running

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium, browser-automation

Can you help me to relove this error?
I use Appium + java for my automation framework. I am running tests on Andorid emulator and here is the capabilities

```
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus_5X_API_28");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
        cap.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","C:\\Users\\xxx\\eclipse-new-workspace\\xxxProject\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"Chrome");
        cap.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
```

I am getting this error when run the tests.

Encountered internal error running command: Error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: 'C:\Users\xxxx\chromedriver.exe --url-base=wd/hub --port=8000 --adb-port=5037 --verbose')

## All log details

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'AAD-85BQ573', ip: '192.168.1.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\eclipse-new-workspace\\xxx\\resources\\chromedriver.exe --url-base\=wd/hub --port\=8000 --adb-port\=5037 --verbose')
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'AAD-85BQ573', ip: '192.168.1.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at pages.BaseSetUp.driverSetUp(BaseSetUp.java:187)
    at steps.CommonSteps.i_am_on_home_page(CommonSteps.java:27)
    at ✽.I am on home page(file:///C:/Users/xxx/eclipse-new-workspace/xxx/src/test/java/features/SignUp_And_SignIn/login.feature:5)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:336)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:88)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:98)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at pages.BaseSetUp.driverSetUp(BaseSetUp.java:187)
    at steps.CommonSteps.i_am_on_home_page(CommonSteps.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:104)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:71)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:135)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:199)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:90)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:234)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: 'C:\\Users\\AsangaKorala\\eclipse-new-workspace\\InnovateProject\\resources\\chromedriver.exe --url-base\=wd/hub --port\=8000 --adb-port\=5037 --verbose')
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'AAD-85BQ573', ip: '192.168.1.78', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '15.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Can't stop process; it's not currently running (cmd: 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\eclipse-new-workspace\\xxx\\resources\\chromedriver.exe --url-base\=wd/hub --port\=8000 --adb-port\=5037 --verbose')
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:392:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Any help with this please?

Comment: Please include your Test-case code snippet

Comment: This is now solved. Problem was with corrupted executables https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=95.0.4638.69/.  Windows chrome exucutables in above link doesn;t work. I have used 95.0.4638.54 chromeverison executables and all good now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved. This is due to following corrupted executables https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=95.0.4638.69/. I have given version 95.0.4638.54 and all working fine.